# guard against a divide by zero error

Tags: python, django

In a python/django app we are developing I am getting a divide by zero error when an html template is rendered. The culprit is the following line ...

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width: {{ account.de_paid|mul:100|div:account.de_owing|floatformat:"0" }}%"><span class="center"><strong>{{ account.de_paid|mul:100|div:account.de_owing|floatformat:"0" }}%</strong></span></div>
```

The values for account.de_paid and account.de_owing are of course passed into the page by the view. Question is ... how can I guard against this divide by zero problem since account.de_owing is frequently zero? Advice?

Comment: Check to see if the values are 0 before entering them into your equation. If not zero, do math.

Answer (score 0):

Because anyhow, dividing by zero will return NaN, and you possibly wish to yield a more significative message, I'd use a conditional around:

```
{% if account.de_owing == 0 %}
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 0%;"><span class="center"><strong>?</strong></span></div>
{% else %}
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width: {{ account.de_paid|mul:100|div:account.de_owing|floatformat:"0" }}%;"><span class="center"><strong>{{ account.de_paid|mul:100|div:account.de_owing|floatformat:"0" }}%</strong></span></div>
{% endif %}
```

(Btw, you are missing a semicolon after the `width` within the inline style).

Comment: Thanks, worked a peach! Inherited this project, still getting my head around some of the code.